# How to call a fetch request and wait for it's answer inside a onBeforeRequest in a web extension

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, request, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a web extension that stops the requests from a url list provided locally, fetches the URL's response, analyzes it in a certain way and based on the analysis results, blocks or doesn't block the request.
Is that even possible?
The browser doesn't matter.
If it's possible, could you provide some examples?

I tried doing it with Chrome extensions, but it seems like it's not possible.
I heard it's possible on mozilla though

Comment: Please use [chrome.declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is only possible using the old webRequestBlocking API which Chrome is [removing as a part of Manifest v3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#network-request-modification). Fortunately, Firefox is planning to continue supporting blocking web requests even as they transition to manifest v3 (read more [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2022/11/17/manifest-v3-signing-available-november-21-on-firefox-nightly/)).

In terms of implementation, I would highly recommend referring to the MDN documentation for webRequest, in particular [their section on modifying responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest#modifying_responses) and their documentation for the [filterResponseData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData#examples) method.

Mozilla have also provided a great [example project](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/4e83c4d4b6af86380484af0ab8da37c80fc89405/http-response) that demonstrates how to achieve something very close to what I think you want to do.

Below I've modified their `background.js` code slightly so it is a little closer to what you want to do:

```js
function listener(details) {
  if (mySpecialUrls.indexOf(details.url) === -1) {
    // Ignore this url, it's not on our list.
    return {};
  }

  let filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
  let decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  let encoder = new TextEncoder();

  filter.ondata = event => {
    let str = decoder.decode(event.data, {stream: true});
    // Just change any instance of Example in the HTTP response
    // to WebExtension Example.
    str = str.replace(/Example/g, 'WebExtension Example');
    filter.write(encoder.encode(str));
    filter.disconnect();
  }

  // This is a BlockingResponse object, you can set parameters here to e.g. cancel the request if you want to.
  // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/BlockingResponse#type
  return {};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  // 'main_frame' means this will only affect requests for the main frame of the browser (e.g. the HTML for a page rather than the images, CSS, etc. that are loaded afterwards). You might want to look into whether you want to expand this.
  {urls: ["*://*/*"], types: ["main_frame"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

**Correction:**
The above example only works properly if the response data fits in one chunk. If it is larger (and you still want to inspect the entirety of the response data), you would need to put all of the data into a buffer, and then work on it once all data has been received. See the document here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter/ondata#webextension_examples (the code section titled "This example combines all buffers into a single buffer" would be of most interest to you I think).

In terms of using this API to block responses, data is only returned from this URL if you call `filter.write()`, so if you don't like the response, you can simply not call it (just call `filter.close()`) and an empty response will be returned. You can also only return part of the full response body by `filter.write()`ing only the bits that you want to return.

Comment: Thank you! Great and extensive answer! Will look into everything more!o be more precise, I'm trying to build an adblocker, that blocks only the ads that it determines malicious, based on the structure of the url and the response that URL gives. I have a list of 57000+ urls from an adblocker filter list and I've built enough to block all those urls, yet I need to anazyle them. Maybe you can add more info based on my provided facts?

Comment: @MartynasJurkėnas sorry for the slow reply! I've added some more info that I hope will help :)